# DAE Object is not Visible in application(runtime)?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I am facing some  DAE issue with my ARKit development.

I exported my 3D model from Autodesk max in DAE format and imported it in Xcode, its working fine in Xcode, but its not visible in my Application.

I even tried from Maya also but i don't see any result, am really clueless.
But when i use any downloaded model from google sketch up its works fine then.

But i want to use my very own model, What could be the issue?

Comment: Maybe your model is too large, ARKit uses meter as unit. Check the scale of your model.

Answer (score 0):

When I converted .dae to .scn it switched my anchors and messed up some stuff so I used .dae with no problems. Try to open it in blender and change the pivot point. 
(1.) If you are trying to place it on detected plane you need to move your phone first to detect something. Try not to place it on plane first, to make sure it is visible. 
(2.) Make sure you are not placing it far from camera - the units are meters here! 
 The last reason can be culling of back faces - make sure your model planes are facing out - otherwise they will not be visible.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the file into a .SCN file inside xCode. Click on the .DAE and it should ask you to convert it. If it not offering you to convert the file then you can do manually be opening your DAE file in the SceneKit scene editor, then go to the Editor menu and click "Convert to scn file format".

Additionally you’ll need to add lighting within SceneKit within xcode. You can see the model on xcode but it will be “dark” in your app. When exporting from Maya the lighting is lost. Unity doesn’t have this issue.